# python runserver performing system checks stays indefinitely

Tags: python

I am using Python2.7.12 and when i try to open web server with run server command, I stacked at performing system checks command. What can be the problem? How can I  pass this and open the web server?

[run server performing system checks stays indefinitely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l826B.png)

Comment: Please post your output as text, not as an image!

Comment: Please check which version of django you are using because django2 doesn't support python2